# Подсчет количества файлов в директории на удаленном сервере

Tags: android, java

Пишу приложение, которое показывает галерею из картинок, расположенных на удаленном сервере.
Как узнать количество файлов в дирректории (напр. "http://www.example.com/dir/"), чтобы потом загрузить их в gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть доступ к серверу, можно написать простой скрипт, выдающий количество файлов в директории, и поместить его куда-нибудь вроде:

```
http://www.example.com/dir/my_counter_script<.php>
```

Далее просто обращаться к нему из приложения.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае никак. Возможные пути обхода:
 1. Выводит ли сервер список файлов, если перейти "http://www.example.com/dir/"
 2. Получить список, спарсив информацию откуда-нибудь.
 3. Самый надежный - какое-нибудь API, которое отдаст список.

**Обновление**

Если сервер подконтрольный вам, то почему бы не реализовать API?

Если картинки добавляются разными способами, можно по крону запускать индексатор. Но это порождает проблемы неактуальных данных.

Если нужно четко знать количество картинок и не ограничивать себя в работе с ними, необходимо любые действия производить через API, которое будет все контролировать.

Comment: Обновил ответ